# Loading/Saving CompiledST

Tags: java, stringtemplate

I am creating a java software which uses StringTemplate to generate C code.
However, I don't want to directly include my templates directly in the jar for the final release, so I'm looking for a way to obfuscate my templates.

Looking quickly into StringTemplate source code, I saw that it uses an intermediate bytecode contained in the "CompiledST" object.

So my question is: Is it possible to save and load this bytecode to avoid releasing plain text templates?

Comment: Trying to do basically the same thing but in my case I have templates defined in MongoDB and I want to load them in memory and cache them for a while (5-10 min) so I'd like to store their compiled version for performance since they could get used many times.

Comment: I guess in my case the question is: is it worth it?